# How can I #evaluate a Velocity Variable within a logic statement?

Tags: java, apache, velocity

I am using Apache Velocity templates.

In the following I loop from 1..n and expect `$myVar` to be equal to a concatenation of the value of `$originalVar` and '_n' (where n is a number from 1..n) e.g. 'test_1' where 'test' is the value of `$originalVar` and 1 is the value of `n`.

This can be achieved as follows :

```
#foreach($i in [1 .. $num_of_iterations])
    #set($myVar= "$originalVar_$i")
    #evaluate($myVar)
#end
```

However, I am unable to #evaluate within a logic statement as per below:

```
#if (#evaluate($myVar)  == "false")
    ...
#end
```

Therefore, how can I `#evaluate` a variable within a logic statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just enclose the #evaluate into quotes:

```
#foreach($i in [1 .. $num_of_iterations])
    #set($myVar= "$originalVar_$i")
    #if("#evaluate($myVar)" == "true")
      found true
    #else
      found false
    #end
#end
```